# How to configure gulpjs such that, the ngrok module can be used to serve url for pagespeed insight plugin?

Tags: javascript, optimization, gulp, pagespeed, ngrok

This is my curreny folder structure:

|-src 
   |-dist 
  |-gulpjs.js

Inside my gulpjs file, I created two tasks for mobile and desktop each, as suggested in [here](https://github.com/addyosmani/psi-gulp-sample/blob/master/gulpfile.js)-

```
gulp.task('mobile', function () {
  return ngrok.connect(4000, function (err, url) {
    psi(url, {
        nokey: 'true',
        strategy: 'mobile',
      }).then(function (data) {
          console.log('Speed score: ' + data.ruleGroups.SPEED.score);
          console.log('Usability score: ' + data.ruleGroups.USABILITY.score);
      });
  });
});

gulp.task('desktop', function () {
  return ngrok.connect(4000, function (err, url) {
    psi(url, {
          nokey: 'true',
          strategy: 'desktop',
      }).then(function (data) {
          console.log('Speed score: ' + data.ruleGroups.SPEED.score);
      });
  });
});
```

When I run gulp mobile or gulp desktop tasks, it DOES give me the speed score in the log, but I am not sure if the url is being generated from src or the dist folder. 
Is there a better way of achieving what I want (I want the pagespeed scored for my local environment)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [swank](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swank) to serve your dist folder with ngrok:

```
// Serve dist folder
gulp.task('serve', function(cb){
    swank({
        watch: false,
        path: 'dist',
        log: false,
        port: 4000
    }).then(function(s){
    console.log('Server running: '+s.url);
    cb();
  });
});

// PageSpeed task
gulp.task('psi-mobile', function() {
   return ngrok.connect(4000, function (err_ngrok, url) {
     console.log(('ngrok'), '- serving your site from', (url));
     pageSpeed.output(url, {
       strategy: ['mobile'],
       threshold: 80
     }, function (err_psi, data) {
       if (err_psi) {
         log(err_psi);
         process.exit(1);
      }
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
});

// Run PSI on tunnel URL
gulp.task('mobile', gulpSequence('serve', 'psi-mobile'));
```